# Something is slow in my code, any suggestions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of big records and I need to loop through each record, add some filter and calculation and add it to my another list. I think doing one by one is affecting the performance because it's taking like 12s to show 900 records.

I am unable to identify why it's taking too long. I used my chrome developer tool to identify where it's slow. Then I came to find out loading taking 0.2s, scripting taking 3s, rendering taking 3s, idle is 3s and others are two seconds.

Maybe I am using Entity Framework and DataTables is making it slow. Or maybe something wrong is with my query. Following is my code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string language)
{
 var All_Employees = from employee in db.Employees
                     .Include(x => x.Country).Include(x => x.Status)
                     where enployee.GenderId == id
                     select employee ;

 var List = new List<EmployeeListViewModel>();

 foreach(var Record in All_Employees.ToList()
         .OrderByDescending(x=> ParseDate(x.JoiningDate)))
 {
      EmployeeListViewModel item = new EmployeeListViewModel();
      item.Id = Record.Id;
      item.Code = Record.Code;
      if(Record.CountryId != null)
      {
          if(language == "en")
          {
             item.Country = Record.Country.NameE;
          }
          else
          {
             item.Country = Record.Country.NameA;
          }
      }

      item.Date = Record.JoiningDate;
      int WorkingDays = 0;
      if(Record.JoiningDate != null)
      {
        DateTime Joining= Convert.ToDateTime(ParseDate(Record.Record.JoiningDate));

        TimeSpan t = DateTime.Now.Date - Joining;
        int Days = int.Parse(t.TotalDays.ToString());
        if (Days > 0)
        {
            WorkingDays = Days;
        }
      }
      item.Days = WorkingDays.ToString();

      if (Record.StatusId != null)
      {
         if (language == "en")
         {
            item.Status = Record.Status.NameE;
         }
         else
         {
            item.Status = Record.Status.NameE;
         }
      }

     List.Add(item);
 }
 return View(List);
}
```

Another reason could be I am converting my date:

```
private static DateTime? ParseDate(string dateString)
{
   if(dateString != null)
   {
     return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
   }
   else
   {
     return null;
   }           
}
```

I don't want to make date filed as DateTime in my database, due to some reasons.

What's the best way to improve performance in my current situation?

Comment: *Another reason could be I am converting my date:* -- well, verify. Try without this conversion.

Comment: @GertArnold I tried but still taking approximately same time.

Comment: `Add` v.s `AddRange` is extremely unlikely to make any noticeable difference with this kind of numbers. You have to eliminate this step by step, which is something only you can do. And which makes your question rather broad: "something is slow in my code, any suggestions"?

Comment: Dear, thanks for your advice. I am changing the title of my question. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I was trying to tell you that the question in this form is off-topic on Stack Overflow *because* it's too broad. You yourself have to eliminate this step by step.

Comment: Can you first check how much time your query is taking to fetch records from database. Only after that, analyse the `for loop`. However, your code doesn't make sense because you are not using `All_Employees` anywhere.

Comment: Mistake in my code @SahilSharma. It's `foreach(var Record in All_Employees.ToList()`

Comment: Comment everything except the first statement where you're fetching records from Db and check the exact time taken.

Comment: As a thumb rule, start from top and check for time consuming factors in your code and analyse the root cause. Break down the problem into smaller chunks. Asking here without self analysis won't guarantee an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion. Show I use Chrome developer tool to check time consuming factors or is there any good tool in Visual Studio to do it,

Comment: why do you materialize All_Employees right in the foreach loop? That is quite risky performance wise.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Presumably so `ParseDate` can be used which can't be done on the SQL side.

Comment: Visual Studio has a full performance suite. Your Chrome timing aren't very helpful to point at where this code is slow. How do you know `View()` isn't the bottleneck?

Comment: @NetMage still materializing could be done before the foreach loop, not within.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Why do you believe that would make a performance difference?

Comment: @NetMage because EF tends to be stupid. I don't know if it's the case here, but I had the issue EF was materializing right the value it was at in the loop with one query each a few times, which obviously takes a long time.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I believe that would happen regardless of whether you materialized in the `foreach` or in a variable before. Both generate the same code.

Comment: I found that from the database records are fetching in 1s. The problem is DataTables and in the View, I am looping through each record to generate table row. This one taking too long. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Too much casting is used here in your code and list is created twice. One way you can do code like below.

```
 List<EmployeeListViewModel> lstData = EmployeeListViewModel.ToList();
 for(int i = 0; i < lstData.Count; i++)
 {
     //Put logic here for required changes like Language and Date.
     if(lstData[i].CountryId != null)
     {
          if(language == "en")
             lstData[i].Country = lstData[i].Country.NameE;
          else
             lstData[i].Country = lstData[i].Country.NameA;
      }
 }
```

Try to reduce casting specially for string and date-time. Below is example.

```
int Days = int.Parse(t.TotalDays.ToString());
```

In above line t.TotalDays is always int type, no need to cast to string and int again.

Comment: Dear, I am filling my `EmlployeeListViewModel` from `All_Employees'. I need to Convert string Date to Date Time since I need to sort by date. How can I improve my code to make it faster?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense. For one, what is `lstData`? Then, you keep accessing the indexer `lstData[i]` while that should only be done once. And finally, `lstData[i].Country = lstData[i].Country.NameE` can't even compile.

Comment: Above code won't compile because it's just example how you can minimize lines of code. But once you have List of EmlployeeListViewModel you can manage it as you wish. TryParse actually internally throws exception if provided value is wrong. This reduces the performance of application.